# Magento 2 : issue with service class of API (Message: Notice: Undefined index: entity_id)

Tags: magento2, api

***this is error:***

> var//log/debug.log:[2019-12-10 10:59:36] main.CRITICAL: Report ID:
>   webapi-5def7a98e911d; Message: Notice: Undefined index: entity_id in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento2_3/app/code/SimplifiedMagento/Custom2/Model/PositionRepository.php
>   on line 46 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID:
>   webapi-5def7a98e911d; Message: Notice

***This is my service method:***

```
public function getDetails($email)
        {
            $emailId = $email;
           $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
         $arr =  $customer->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['entity_id'])->addFieldToFilter('email',$emailId)->getData();
           $entityId = $arr['entity_id'];

           //entity id is above

           $customTable = $this->addDataFactory->create();
          $array = $customTable->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['position'])->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$entityId)->getData();
            $position = $array['position'];
            $obj = $this->positionInterfaceFactory->create()->setPosition($position);
            return $obj;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
$entityId = $arr['entity_id'];
```

With this

```
$entityId = isset($arr['entity_id']) ? $arr['entity_id'] : '';
```

**Update**

```
public function getDetails($email)
{
  $emailId = $email;
  $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
  $arr =  $customer->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['entity_id'])->addFieldToFilter('email',$emailId)->getData();
  $entityId = isset($arr['entity_id']) ? $arr['entity_id'] : '';

  //entity id is above
  if($entityId){
    $customTable = $this->addDataFactory->create();
    $array = $customTable->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['position'])->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$entityId)->getData();
    $position = isset($array['position']) ? $array['position'] : 0;
    $obj = $this->positionInterfaceFactory->create()->setPosition($position);
    return $obj;
  }else{
    return "Entity ID is missing!";
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: is this a correct way to "select with WHERE clause" in magento 2.3?

Comment: $arr =  $customer->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['entity_id'])->addFieldToFilter('email',$emailId)->getData();

Comment: Yes, that will return entity ID of given email id

Comment: should $emailId be in double quotes since it is string?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you're asking here.

Comment: $array = $customTable->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(['position'])->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$entityId)->getData();

Comment: in addFieldToFilter method $entityId has to be in double quotes?

Comment: No, It is correct. no need to add quotes there.

Comment: the $entityId is appearing empty?

Comment: Approve answer if it is helpful to you then. Thanks :)